# How to display array as an image without borders

Tags: image, julia

I want to display this matrix A= [1 1; 0 1] as an image. The result with the Gray. method is the following:

```
A = [1 1;0 1]
Display(Gray.(A))
```

[image]

But I dont want the grid lines, is there an alternative way to achieve that?

Comment: show us your code so far...

Comment: @Mark A=[1 1;0 1];
Display(Gray.(A))

Comment: ERROR: UndefVarError: `Gray` not defined

Answer (score 0):

This will heavily depend on what you want to do (and the question is not specific)

For an example you could plot with ASCII using UnicodePlots:

```
UnicodePlots.heatmap(A,labels=false,border=:none,colormap=(z, zmin, zmax) -> z*255)
```

[image]

If you are rather into `using Images`:

```
Images.save("im.png",Images.colorview(Gray, A))
```

[image]

If you want rather display this on screen consider `using Plots`

```
Plots.plot(Images.colorview(Gray, A), border=:none, labels=false
```

[image]

Comment: Also `using ImageInTerminal, UnicodePlots, Images; g = Gray.([1 1 ; 0 1])` works on my REPL.